# Is it possible to set the cursor at the end of the string found?

Tags: search, vim

I'm using VIM 7.1

When I search a string in file, the cursor is moved to the beginning of the string found in the text.

Can the cursor be moved at the end instead of the start of the string ?

> ```
> String where I'm looking for the search
> ```

I want cursor at the g of king when I look for `king`

- I tried to go to previous result `:N`
- I tried to search with `?`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `/king/e`. The e means put the cursor at the end of the match. `:help search-offset` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; use zero-look-behind

```
/\(king\)\@<=\
```

(Note: there's a space at the end of that line)

Basically, you're looking for the space that follows 'king', and that will jump to it.

Comment: Wow! +1 But it's easier to remember the `/e` (end)

Comment: This is not working in my tests. Can you elaborate on the syntax after the close parenthesis?

Comment: Basically, A\@<=B means "Find 'B' if and only if it follows 'A'". You can do negative, too: A\@<=!B means "Find 'B' if and only if it *does not* follow 'A'".  More: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/vim/searching.html

Answer (score 0):

```
nnoremap ,n //e<CR>:let @/=@/<CR>
```